# asp.net Remember Me System with FormsAuthenticationTicket

Tags: asp.net, formsauthenticationticket

I am trying to do Remember Me system on a asp.net project. I did user registration and login FormsAuthenticationTicket. What I want is when user login, I set a persistent cookie as expected, I validate that I can add the cookie but FormsAuthenticationTicket doesnt handle the remembering thing. here is my code

```
ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
                                            (String)(drUserInfo["Email"]),
                                            DateTime.Now,
                                            DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
                                            Login1.RememberMeSet,
                                            (String)(drUserInfo["UserType"]));
                encryptedStr = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
```

Can you help me with this? Does FormsAuthenticationTicket handle the remember me system or me?

Comment: FormsAuthentication handles it. There is a checkbox in the asp:Login control which sets the encrypted cookie

Comment: You might want to use ILSpy and examine whats going on in the asp:Login controls code

Comment: I see there is an encrypted cookie created by login control. but still doesnt work

Comment: Okay from the asp:Login source code I see they set the cookie using the code in my answer(just writing it now

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the source code for the asp:Login I see that the cookie is reated with the following call:

call made from System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AttemptLogin

```
if (authenticateEventArgs.Authenticated)
{
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(this.UserNameInternal, this.RememberMeSet);
    this.OnLoggedIn(EventArgs.Empty);
    this.Page.Response.Redirect(this.GetRedirectUrl(), false);
    return;
}
```

`FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(this.UserNameInternal, this.RememberMeSet);` is the call